# How do I delete a related task in Redmine?

Tags: redmine

In one of my Redmine issues, I added a 'related task'. Now I want to remove that related task. When I select the triple dots icon for that task relation, and select 'delete', nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the paperclip, that should remove the relation.